# Cuda ubuntu and docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cuda

I regularly install cuda on different ubuntu (14.04) machines and depending on the specific machine setup it can sometimes be very tricky (days of installation).

I was wondering whether using docker containers could ease the installation... well virtually their would be a single installation a container then the container would ne deployed everywhere. I would only have the installation hassle once, right? Or am I totally wrong on what docker actually brings?

Thanks,

Antoine.

Comment: Have you already looked at the tooling [NVIDIA](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Why%20NVIDIA%20Docker) provides for this?

Comment: This is a very relevant link, thanks!

Comment: From reading [this link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA) I understand that the NVIDIA driver cannot be containerized, only CUDA can, is that right? I am not sure I understand why: when installing the NVIDIA driver, the installation is totally hardware agnostic and the same driver can be used on any computer, no? Does it mean that during the installation, the driver only installs what is needed for the specific hardware of the machine, and thus the genericity is lost?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure, I haven't done anything with CUDA. I was just wondering if that's something you've seen already and weren't able to use. Makes the question easier to answer for people who know more.

Comment: Skimming over [this](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers), my guess is that NVIDIA drivers install a kernel module to do their job better. Docker images are just a file system, all containers share the same kernel. You probably can't run a container that adds its own kernel modules without messing with all of the other containers.

Comment: Thanks R0MANARMY ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats right, You need to follow these steps:

1. create a new container from base image if your choice
2. make changes
3. commit your changes
4. Push your image to your repository
5. Use it to launch containers when ever you need.

Things to keep in mind:

1. The best way to do this is using a dockerfile.
2. there are many best practices for creating efficent containers.
3. You may want to use available images made by experts.

Please check [this link](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda), its better to use this if thats what you need.

Comment: From reading [this link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA) I understand that the NVIDIA driver cannot be containerized, only CUDA can, is that right? I am not sure I understand why: when installing the NVIDIA driver, the installation is totally hardware agnostic and the same driver can be used on any computer, no? Does it mean that during the installation, the driver only installs what is needed for the specific hardware of the machine, and thus the genericity is lost?

Comment: The container doesn't have the driver. The host Machine must have at least one CUDA-capable GPU and a driver compatible with the CUDA toolkit.